# Is it possible to select all text fields in a view?

Tags: swift

So my code looks like this, targeting each known textfield and applying the same modifier to them.

Is there some way I can just select all textfields in the view?

```
import UIKit

class CreateAccount: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewer: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var reenterPasswordTextField: UITextField!

    let textFieldBorderColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 170.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let textFieldBorderFocusedColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 31.0/255.0, green: 111.0/255.0, blue: 217.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        usernameTextField.layer.borderColor = textFieldBorderColor.CGColor
        emailTextField.layer.borderColor = textFieldBorderColor.CGColor
        passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = textFieldBorderColor.CGColor
        reenterPasswordTextField.layer.borderColor = textFieldBorderColor.CGColor

        usernameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        emailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        reenterPasswordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        scrollViewer.delegate = self


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to **subclass** a `UITextField` and then inherit from this subclass all of your UITextField elements.

Then you will need to apply properties / styles for this subclass only.

For example (written in ***Swift 3.0***):

```
class MyCustomTextField: UITextField {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: MyCustomTextField!
...

func viewDidLoad () {
    // you don't need to apply style properties here anymore 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to instantly select all text-fields but if you are looking for a way to save space you can try adding all your text fields to an array an then looping through to make the changes.

```
import UIKit

class CreateAccount: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewer: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var reenterPasswordTextField: UITextField!



let textFieldBorderColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 170.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let textFieldBorderFocusedColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 31.0/255.0, green: 111.0/255.0, blue: 217.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var textFieldArray = [usernameTextField, emailTextField, passwordTextField, reenterPasswordTextField]

    for textField in textFieldArray {

       textField.layer.borderColor = textFieldBorderColor.CGColor
       textField.layer.borderWidth =  1.0
    }



    scrollViewer.delegate = self


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This would select all the UITextField subviews of a view:

```
let textfields = view.subviews.filter({$0.isKindOfClass(UITextField)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@IBOutlet` collection to apply properties to multiple like properties.

You can connect UI elements twice.

Once to their unique `@IBOutlet` connection and once to the `@IBOutlet` collection

[image]

This expresses as `[UITextField!]` in Swift and as `IBOutletCollection(UITextField)` in Objective-C

So...

**Swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet var allTextFields: [UITextField]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for field in allTextFields {
            field.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }

    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text3;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *allTextFields;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (UITextField *field in self.allTextFields) {
        field.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}


@end
```

removes the need for subclassing and maintaining manual arrays

You can also get as generic as you need to and define the collection as a bundle of `UIView` if you need to.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *allViews;`